# Python API client doesn't recognize 'login' type for Reports API

Tags: google-api-python-client, google-admin-sdk

I've been trying to use Python and a service account to access the new Reports API to download user login information. I can successfully build a service account, and then I try to call activities.list using ApplicationName='login' (see snippet below).

```
def createAuditService():
  f = file(my-private-key, 'rb')
  key = f.read()
  f.close()

  credentials = SignedJwtAssertionCredentials(my-service-account, key,
      scope='https://www.googleapis.com/auth/admin.reports.audit.readonly')
  http = httplib2.Http()
  http = credentials.authorize(http)

  return build('reports', 'v1', http=http)

def retrieveActivites(service):
  try:
    Logins = service.activities().list(userKey='all',applicationName='login').execute()
    return Logins.get('items',[])
  except errors.HttpError, error:
    log.error('An error occurred.',exc_info=True)
  return None

def main():    
  service = createAuditService()    
  activities = retrieveActivites(service)
  print activities
```

Instead I get the following error:

```
2013-11-28 09:51:17,727 - apiclient.discovery - INFO - URL being requested: https://www.googleapis.com/discovery/v1/apis/reports/v1/rest
2013-11-28 09:51:17,727 - oauth2client.client - INFO - Attempting refresh to obtain initial access_token
2013-11-28 09:51:18,135 - oauth2client.client - INFO - Refreshing access_token
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "F:\Dropbox\code\glogin-audit\glogin.py", line 105, in <module>
    main()
  File "F:\Dropbox\code\glogin-audit\glogin.py", line 91, in main
    activities = retrieveActivites(service)
  File "F:\Dropbox\code\glogin-audit\glogin.py", line 75, in retrieveActivites
    Logins = service.activities().list(userKey='all',applicationName='login').execute()
  File "build\bdist.win32\egg\apiclient\discovery.py", line 595, in method
    (name, pvalue, regex))
TypeError: Parameter "applicationName" value "login" does not match the pattern "(admin)|(docs)"
```

Using 'admin' or 'docs' values instead of 'login' for the applicationName parameter produces valid data, so I'm fairly sure I have the syntax right (see the API reference [here](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/reports/v1/reference/activities/list), and the Python client reference [here](https://developers.google.com/resources/api-libraries/documentation/admin/reports_v1/python/latest/admin_reports_v1.activities.html#list)).

Also, I was having the problem with the Python client v1.1, but I'm having the same problem after I upgraded to 1.2: `easy_install --upgrade google-api-python-client`

Any suggested next steps?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to replace the last line of your createAuditService() function:

```
return build('reports', 'v1', http=http)
```

with:

```
return build('admin', 'reports_v1', http=http)
```

in order to get the latest version of the discovery document which supports login reports.